# How can I display an image on a web page in django that is on my desktop?

Tags: html, css, django, image

I am loading data from postgresSQL database. This data is stored in the database by my python program. Not I am fetching data with the same functions I am using in my program. I want to create a bar chart before displaying it on my HTML webpage in Django. I created a chart using matplotlib and saved it on the desktop. Now I want to fetch that image and display it. I tried giving a link directly to that image but that doesn't load the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/):

1. In your settings file, define `STATIC_URL`, for example:

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
2. In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL:

   `{% load static %}
   <img src="{% static "example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">`
3. Store your `example.jpg` image file in a folder called `static` in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly render the image in your python function with matplotlib. After that, you will store the image to your server. You can then can get the link and pass it to the django template. Just render the img tag with the link as the src attribute.